# Problem with using external HDD

Tags: external-hdd

First i used command

```
lsblk
```

and my external HDD was not there

then I

```
lsusb
```

and it is showing my external HDD

but i could not see my HDD in disks app as well

I am new to this environment and dont know what to do?

Comment: Welcome to AK. You might want to add the output of `dmesg | tail` command after connecting the HDD. I suspect there is a filesystem problem, so a filesystem check may be needed.

Comment: ```dmesg | tail``` after entering this command i could not see my external drive. also my usb port is working fine as i have already used pen drive from it

Comment: Make sure you unplug the USB cable, and replug it, before running `dmesg | tail`. You want to see what is logged when the HDD is plugged in. Alternatively, run `dmesg | tail -f` first, then replug the HDD.

Comment: yes it is showing now my external HDD. now what to do

Comment: what to do now please help

Comment: What to do depends on you output you got. If it is a bunch of errors, then deal with them, on the other hand, if the HDD got a name like /dev/sdX, then try to mount a partition manually. You may want to copy paste the output and add it to the question. This way we'll know what it was.

Comment: ```[112577.816907] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[112577.816909] usb 2-1.3: Product: HV100
[112577.816911] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: ADATA
[112577.816913] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 461087184045
[112577.817288] usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[112577.817455] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[112578.844210] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ADATA    HV100            9102 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[112578.844708] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[112578.848633] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
```

Comment: ```[112579.867496] ........not responding... ```

Comment: OK, thanks for that. By "add the output to the question", I meant [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1135469/edit) the question, and add the output to it, and not post it as a comment. ...sorry for not being clear. It would be interesting to know what you connect the HDD to. Is it to a USB hub? Are there other USB devices connected to the same USB port? What kind of a computer it is, desktop, laptop or a development board like RaspberryPi. As with the above output, you might want to edit the question itself, and add the info.